# jQuery templates - how to get value of user-edited input

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I run into a problem while using jQuery templates (http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

First: defined a template like this one:

```
 <td>
      <input type="text" value="${Text}" />
</td>
```

When it renders user types some text into it, but I don't know how to get what he types. All I receive is old "value" attribute value.

The code I use to get data back:

```
var enteredData = row.tmplItem();     
var note = enteredData.data;

var data = {};
data.NoteId = note.NoteId;
data.NoteText = note.Text;
```

I'd be grateful for any help!

Thank you!

Comment: I think more information might be needed here.  For instance, I see no relationship with the markup you present and the code from what you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
$('input').val()
```

to get the entered value
(obviously it would be best to give the input an id so you don't call all inputs on the page!)

Comment: I tried this, but it only gives me old value (not the new value that user types).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" value="${Text}" id="text${id}"/>
   </td>
```

and

```
$('#text'+ id).val() //if you want a specific one of more inputs
```

or just set a static id if you only have one....